# Qt WebEngine: Get error reasons in QWebEnginePage::loadFinished and QWebEnginePage::pdfPrintingFinished

Tags: c++, qwebengine

Signal `QWebEnginePage::loadFinished` has a `bool ok` parameter and signal `QWebEnginePage::pdfPrintingFinished` has a `bool success` parameter that indicate if there was an error. But both signals don't have any additional error information. Is there a way to get detailed error information about HTML parsing and PDF creation?

I want to convert a self generated HTLM document to a PDF with a QWebEnginePage. Sometime it works, but sometimes `loadFinished` has `ok = false` and the web page is empty. When I save the HTML, Chrome can load it without problems.

PDF generation can always fail for a variety of file system issues and I want to give the user hints how to fix these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue recently, which might be due to the fact that there is a 2 MB limit described [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebengineview.html#setHtml).

I was able to finally display the HTML page, loading it from a temporary/transitory file where I dumped the HTML string. But I did not find a way to save such big HTML pages as PDF. Note that when I tried to display this HTML page on Chrome (which is based on Chromium, that Qt is using if I'm right), I also had an error when trying to export it as a PDF.